# MySQL group - fetch data across 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following structure of tables:

`cars`

```
- id
- brand
- location
```

`car_services`:

```
- id
- car_id
- service_id
```

`services`

```
- id
- service_name
```

What I am trying to do is to get a list of `service_name`s with count of occurrence cars in a certain location (sorted out by the occurrence).

For example - I'd like to know what are the top services of cars in Texas.

I am sorry if the way I explained what I am trying to get complicatedly - if so, I'll try to explain it better.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `id` in the `car_services` table do? Beyond that, and if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want a result something like this:

```
service_name | location   | count
-------------+------------+------
service 1    | location 1 |     5
service 2    | location 1 |     4
service 1    | location 2 |     2
```

Which should be achieved with a query like this:

```
SELECT services.service_name, cars.location, count(*) as count
FROM services
JOIN car_services on services.id = car_services.service_id
JOIN cars on cars.id = car_services.car_id
GROUP BY services.service_name, cars.location
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: But `location` is not in the table `services` - the first line indicate it is, or not?

Comment: Because you're joining across tables, you can select columns from any of those tables.  I'll edit my answer to add explicit table references to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT service_names
, c.location 
, COUNT(c.id) car_occ
FROM services s
INNER JOIN car_services cs
on s.id=cs.service_id
inner join cars c
on s.id=c.id
group by service_names, c.location
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try it.